# prove $ \bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[0,2-\frac{1}{2 k+1}\right]=[0,2) $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$
\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[0,2-\frac{1}{2 k+1}\right]=[0,2)
$$

I don't know how to prove backwards $[0,2) \subseteq \cup\left[0,2-\frac{1}{2 k+1}\right]$
If it is less than $2, I$ think it doesn't necessarily less than $2-\frac{1}{2 k+1}$ right?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Archimedean property?

Answer (score 2):

Let $ x\in(0,2)$.
we will prove that there exists $ k\in \Bbb N $ such that

$$0\le x\le 2-\frac{1}{2k+1}$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2k+1}\le 2-x$$
and
$$\frac{1}{2-x}\le 2k+1$$
thus

$$k\ge \frac 12(\frac{1}{2-x}-1)$$
so, you can choose

$$k=\lfloor \frac{x-1}{2(2-x)}\rfloor +1$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x<2$, you can always find some $k$ such that $x<2-1/(2k+1)$.
Look at $2-x$. You just need $1/(2k+1)<2-x$, or $2k+1>1/(2-x)$. There's always an integer larger than a given real number, so you have such a $k$ and can guarantee $[0,2)\subseteq \bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \left[ 0, 2-\frac{1}{2k+1}\right]$.

Comment: *There's always an integer larger than a given real number...* is the core idea of the problem. Perhaps you need to elaborate how do you make that claim.

Comment: I think Christopher's claim is pretty obvious. Take the integer part of the real and add 1.